# looping through 2 arrays javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, for-loop, foreach

i need a bit of help to get a function working correctly. let me explain a few parts so you understand the issue before i show you the function so far.

please note: all the data is being passed in don't worry about anything like that my question is in regards to looping through the data i have stated below and making it work correctly. When this function hits everything is being passed in already.

I have 2 arrays which hold data in them one is called Variants() this always holds 6 Variants which all have a unique ID, and the other is called ProductRequests(). Variants holds ALL my Variants and ProductRequests holds all the chosen variants, this can vary from 1 to 6 so its all down to what they chose, but they have to chose at least one.. no matter what they chose there will always be a match when comparing to Variants() Array IDs.

These both hold IDs which match each other and also quantities, what i want to do is loop through variants and product requests find if any of the ids match and then if they do match the quantity from the ProductRequests overwrite the quantity from the Variants of that product ID. I have done the 2nd part below but it kind of needs to be written a lot better.

What i did was i wrote a function (without any looping through) which compares the IDs of them but what my issue was sometimes depending on what the user picks in the arrays will not match up on the array numbers as ProductRequests for example ProductRequests may only have 1 item in it but that only matches Variant()[5] of the IDs that are in Variants etc. So this hard coded way just would not work.. (well it could but it would be a horrible messy code.)

```
function Compare(){
        var OldVariants = Variants();
        var RequestVariants = ProductRequests();
        var One = OldVariants[0].Id;
        var Two = OldVariants[1].Id;
        var Three = OldVariants[2].Id;
        var Four = OldVariants[3].Id;
        var Five = OldVariants[4].Id;
        var Six = OldVariants[5].Id;

        if (One == RequestVariants[0].Id)
        {OldVariants[0].Quantity(RequestVariants[0].Quantity)}
        if (Two == RequestVariants[1].Id)
        {OldVariants[1].Quantity(RequestVariants[1].Quantity)}
        if (Three == RequestVariants[2].Id)
        {OldVariants[2].Quantity(RequestVariants[2].Quantity)}
        if (Four == RequestVariants[3].Id)
        {OldVariants[3].Quantity(RequestVariants[3].Quantity)}
        if (Five == RequestVariants[4].Id)
        {OldVariants[4].Quantity(RequestVariants[4].Quantity)}
        if (Six == RequestVariants[5].Id)
        {OldVariants[5].Quantity(RequestVariants[5].Quantity)}
        }
```

This function works but like i said above if the user doesn't select the ProductRequests in that order the IDs don't match meaning the values do not get undated.

Any advice or help would be great.

Comment: What is the `Compare` function meant to do? You've said it compares them, but not *how*, or what results you're expecting, or...

Comment: it first sets the ids of variants array to a variable. It then compares that id to the ProductRequest().id.. now what i want to happen is it to loop through the 2 arrays and find any matching IDs in the 2 arrays.. now if there is a match i want it to do a if statement and add the ProductRequests().Quantity of each matched ID into the Variants().Quantity

Comment: Okay, good -- that's what my answer does. :-) (Assuming the `Quantity` function on the `OldVariants` entries does the addition.)

Comment: Ive tried to apply your function.. it gets the first one correctly but its not looping through if there were multiple ProductRequests picked?

Comment: Yes, it does -- that's what `forEach` does.

Comment: Well it seems to return true when it finds 1 match and then finishes?

Comment: And my array has got all the correct data in it?

Comment: That `return true` just stops the **inner** loop (the `some` loop), the outer `forEach` loop continues. I'm assuming there's only one entry in `OldVariants` with each `Id`?

Comment: Within the next function it was variant.Quantity(req.Quantity); i cleared all the requests so it could not find anymore but i removed that part now thanks a lot great answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your goal is to update the entries from `OldVariants` that have the same `Id` as the entries in `RequestVariants`, calling their `Quantity` method with the `Quantity` property of the requested variants, then you either need a loop of loops:

```
function Compare(){
    var OldVariants = Variants();
    var RequestVariants = ProductRequests();

    RequestVariants.forEach(function(req) {
        OldVariants.some(function(variant) {
            if (variant.Id == req.Id) {
                variant.Quantity(req.Quantity);
                return true; // Stops the inner loop
            }
        });
    });
}
```

...or you'll want to build a temporary `Id->Variant` map and then use that:

```
function Compare(){
    var OldVariants = Variants();
    var RequestVariants = ProductRequests();
    var VariantMap = {};

    OldVariants.forEach(function(variant) {
        VariantMap["x" + variant.Id] = variant;
    });

    RequestVariants.forEach(function(req) {
        var variant = VariantMap["x" + req.Id];
        if (variant) {
            variant.Quantity(req.Quantity);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Within the next function it was variant.Quantity(req.Quantity); i cleared all the requests so it could not find anymore but i removed that part now thanks a lot great answer.